# How to get the address of an array element?

Tags: c++, arrays, element

i want to out put an elements address to the console but im having trouble with it.

`cout << &text[0] << endl;`

it seems to is output its vaule, what am i doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: Show the definition of `text`, too.

Comment: not sure what you mean show the definition? lol sorry

Comment: @nullVoid show us where `text` is declared as variable

Comment: its a string array? is there no way to just show the address of the element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert to `void *` for the printing with iostreams, and you need a safe address-of operator that doesn't get confused by overloaded `&`-operators. In other words:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(text[0])) << std::endl;
```

You need `<memory>` and `<iostream>`, as well as a recent compiler.

---

*Update:* Note that this code gives you the *static* address of the operand. If you want to pass a base reference of a polymorphic object, you should use `dynamic_cast<void*>(x)` instead, but this works *only* for polymorphic objects (i.e. those with virtual functions), and it gives you the address of the actual, dynamic object.

Comment: @Jared: iostreams has overloads for things like `char*`. We wouldn't want those, would we?

Comment: *Neo:* You mean, I'll be able to know the type of any of the OP's objects? *Morpheus:* No. When you know C++11, you won't *have* to.

Comment: @KerrekSB What about versions of C++ earlier than `C++11`?

Comment: @Meysam: Look up how [`addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) is implemented and copy that to your code - it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
printf("%p",text);
```

you need `stdio.h` to use printf